# how to get a function to return after running the sql query with nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I got the following nodejs code snippet working. It hangs in the end and does n ot return.  In the end I want to get, insert and delete users based on the status. If the function does not return I cannot do so. I just gives this output.

```
[ { UserName: 'user4',
    LoggedStatus: 'avail',
    UserPass: 'demo',
    UserType: 'gen' },
  { UserName: 'user3',
    LoggedStatus: 'avail',
    UserPass: 'demo',
    UserType: 'gen' },
  { UserName: 'user2',
    LoggedStatus: 'avail',
    UserPass: 'demo',
    UserType: 'gen' },
  { UserName: 'user1',
    LoggedStatus: 'used',
    UserPass: 'demo',
    UserType: 'gen' } ]
```

......(hangs here)....

A) How to get the function getAllRecords() to return and the program to end??
B) Return particular rows or particular values from the DB.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var sql = require("mssql");

var config = {  
    "server": "localhost",
    "user": "xxxx",
    "password": "xxxx",
    "database": "dbTA",
     "port": 1433 
};


function getAllRecords(config) {
    sql.connect(config).then(function() {
        // Query
        new sql.Request().query('select * from USERSTATUS').then(function(recordset) {
            console.log(recordset);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Error1", err);
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error2", err);
    });
}

getAllRecords(config);
```

Comment: Adding  sql.close();  after the console.log(recordset) works !!! I will try to get answer of remaining part. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises are unwrapped using `.then()`, and anything returned in `.then()` will be wrapped in a Promise, allowing you to chain them together.

Let's add some returns and get the value out of your query.

```
var config = {  
  "server": "localhost",
  "user": "xxxx",
  "password": "xxxx",
  "database": "dbTA",
  "port": 1433
};

function getAllRecords(configuration) {
  // return the entire chain of promises
  return sql.connect(configuration)
    .then(function() {
      // return this query so we can have access to its value 
      return new sql.Request().query('select * from USERSTATUS');
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("Error1", err);
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error2", err);
  });
}

// since we're returning a promise we have to consume it using a `.then()`
getAllRecords(config).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Yes, thats an alternative with Promises. However I was looking for sql.close(); in the end to end the program I added it in the end and it solved my problem. Thanks for your reply though. I will mark it as an answer though :-)

Comment: He is already consuming it in `.then`. Not sure if question was updated afterwards.

Comment: Ah I see.  I misunderstood what the actual problem was.

Comment: By the way if I use use following again (which is quite the natural requirement) then I get error:
getAllRecords(config).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
}); and the error is Error1a { ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
    at C:\qpr\trunk\Source\EnticeUI\src\main\frontend\node_modules\mssql\lib\main.js:1569:17
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Connection is closed.',
  code: 'ECONNCLOSED' }

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not closing your DB connection, that active connection is preventing node from ending.

You should close your DB connection in your `then` and `catch` blocks using `sql.close()`

Comment: By the way if I use use following again (which is quite the natural requirement) then I get error: getAllRecords(config).then(function(value) { console.log(value); }); and the error is Error1a { ConnectionError: Connection is closed. at C:\qpr\trunk\Source\EnticeUI\src\main\frontend\node_modules\‌​mssql\lib\main.js:15‌​69:17 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7) at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) name: 'ConnectionError', message: 'Connection is closed.', code: 'ECONNCLOSED' }

Comment: @win Yes, you will have to open connection again, because you closed it in previous function.

That is upto your requirements and scenario, wether to open/close connection everytime or after a set of operations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sachin, but the function getAllRecords() does a sql.connect() everytime it is called. The next time the function is called even if I pass it a new this following sql = require("mssql"); object it complains that connection has been closed and does not connect again. How can I get past this problem?

Comment: create a new connection like this `var connection = new sql.Connection({ /* config */ })`
and then connect using `connection.connect`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#connect-callback